# How to display Sharepoint online office 365 site in aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, html, aspx

I have created an ASP.net web application where I am trying to display a SharePoint Office 365 online site through iframe.

I am getting an error

> XFrame cannot be set to same origin

How to display entire SharePoint site in aspx page? If This is possible, what is the approach which needs to be followed?

Please note I do not have permissions to modify SharePoint master page.

Comment: Did you try inserting a Page viewer Web part and showing the site?

Comment: Didn't try that approach,Is there any blog or code which can explain how SharePoint online site can be displayed.I have an aspx page where SharePoint site needs to be shown and cant modify anything in sharepoint site(PageViewer webpart seems to be related to SharePoint,not very sure about this)

Answer (score 0):

I presume your ASPX page and Office365 are **different** (sub)domains

Cross-domain iframe requests to SharePoint Online organizations are blocked.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2795602

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/12/12/iframing-sharepoint-hosted-pages-in-apps.aspx

Comment: Please can i know if there is any other approach for achieving this as it cannot be done through iframe,i have been stuck with this task for some time now.It would be a great help if i could get any approach(code) for displaying SharePoint site

Comment: You have been given a mission impossible if you are not allowed to change Server Side settings.

Comment: You mean it can only be done by setting <WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" /> in Masterpage.